# Data from csv file is different as given data from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read some data in R via a csv file. The problem that the values change after exporting them to csv type. I tried to edit then using Notepad++ but without any success. This will influence on the correctness of the plot that uses these data.

This is how the data should be shown (from a given a dataframe):

```
     cc_variant       Date        NEE
1      Fallow 2016-10-18   52.31861
2      Fallow 2016-10-19   36.75274
3      Fallow 2016-10-24   34.59082
4        Mix4 2016-10-18 -516.86837
5       Mix12 2016-10-18 -617.11000
6     Mustard 2016-10-18 -182.24568
7        Mix4 2016-10-19 -102.63776
8       Mix12 2016-10-19 -431.55887
9     Mustard 2016-10-19 -139.04121
10    Mustard 2016-10-24 -114.09939
11      Mix12 2016-10-24 -400.21260
12       Mix4 2016-10-24 -175.33208
```

This how the data is shown after reading the csv file:

```
 cc_variant       Date       NEE
1      Fallow 18.10.2016   5231861
2      Fallow 19.10.2016   3675274
3      Fallow 24.10.2016   3459082
4        Mix4 18.10.2016 -51686837
5       Mix12 18.10.2016 -61711000
6     Mustard 18.10.2016 -18224568
7        Mix4 19.10.2016 -10263776
8       Mix12 19.10.2016 -43155887
9     Mustard 19.10.2016 -13904121
10    Mustard 24.10.2016 -11409939
11      Mix12 24.10.2016 -40021260
12       Mix4 24.10.2016 -17533208
```

The problem is only with the **NEE** values.

This is the commande used for reading the data:

```
 data <- read.csv2("C:\\Users\\alex\\Desktop\\orkg-stencila\\Gentsch2020\\data.csv")
    data$NEE <- as.numeric(sub('.', '', data$NEE, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: Can you show the command used for reading file

Comment: @akrun thanks for trying to help me, I update my question :)

Comment: When you do the `sub` to remove the `.`, wouldn't that change from the expected input data

Comment: @akrun you mean use a sub function, I didn't try that to be honest

Comment: I meant `data$NEE <- as.numeric(sub('.', '', data$NEE, fixed = TRUE))`, it removes the `.` in the NEE column.  That is why the values are different

Comment: @akrun now I understand, I didn't know that, I had a problem that the data is taken as string not numeric, someone gives me this function to read the data as numeric, but it causes now this problem, do you have an idea to prohibite that?

Comment: The issue could be that one or more of the elements in that column is not numeric i.e. if an element is "50.56a", then the whole column become character or factor

Comment: ah ok. so shall I remove the sub function and try to convert it one by one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the sub() function. If you want to check the mode of the columns type lapply(data, class) OR as_tibble(data).  If you want to change the data type of a column data$NEE<- as.numeric(data$NEE) OR as.character(data$NEE).  Alternatively type.convert(data$NEE) reduces that column to its base, or simplest data type.i.e. character to numeric.